# Where does Google Chrome store my homepage?

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-chrome

I located the Profiles folder for Chrome, but I'm unable to find any file which stores my homepage.

Basically I want to change my Chrome homepage using VB.NET, but I can't find where it is stored. I have already checked the Registry and in the Profiles folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

A quick glance at the documentation concerning the [User Data Directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) tells us that Chrome stores information and parameters for specific users in the following locations:

> **Windows XP**
>   `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
>
> **Windows Vista**
>       `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

In that folder, you'll find a file named "Preferences". The file is saved in [JSON format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). You can open this file as plain text, search for the string "homepage", and modify one or both of the settings. The first one indicates what Chrome uses as your homepage. The second indicates whether Chrome automatically opens the "New Tab" page (True), or if it navigates to your specified homepage (False).

For example, the relevant two lines in my "Preferences" file look like this:

```
"homepage": "http://www.google.com/",
"homepage_is_newtabpage": true,
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that we can Chrome homepage from entry point of the browser itself. But perhaps your application should be getting admin's permission in that particular machine.

If Im not mistaken, you can set in vb.net so that the app will automatically ask for admin's permission  (UAC)

Comment: Then why don't you tell us how you did it?? Thats why this space is for!!

Answer (score 0):

I like using the adm file from chromium.org.

Download from [here](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates).

Just set your home page via GPO and link it to the OU with the computers.

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Classic Administrative Templates (ADM)\Google\Google Chrome\Home page\
>   Configure the home page URL = enabled

or if you want your users to be able to change it

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Classic Administrative Templates (ADM)\Google\Google Chrome - Default Settings (users can override)\Home page\
>   Configure the home page URL = enabled